# What datatype is the best to store article(text) in GAE database

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, blogs

I plan to make a self-hosted blog. 
I am using Google App Engine for the hosting.

I wanted to know that every 'article' that I store in the database will be of which datatype? 
Should it be a simple String? Or any other specific datatype?

I code in java so answers are expected in java.
Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the list of [properties and value types](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities#Java_Properties_and_value_types) you should use `Text string (long)` if your text is up to 1MB cause the short version is up to 500 characters. If your text is going to be more than 1MB you will have to use [Blobstore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/).

Answer (score 0):

The `String` data type has a size limit for persistence to the datastore using JDO. I do not know if other datastore interfaces get around this limit.

You might want to try the data type `com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Text`. Have a look at the GAE/J javadoc documentation for further details, so that you can decide whether this data type would be useful for you or not.